# What is the meaning of the GCC warning "case label value exceeds maximum value for type"?

Tags: c, gcc, warnings, switch-statement

My code looks like this:

```
char * decode_input(char ch)
{
        switch(ch) {
                case 'g':
                        return "get";
                        break;
                case KEY_F(9):
                        return "quit";
                        break;
                default:
                        return "unknown";
                        break;
        }
}
```

Any clues?

Comment: What does KEY_F do? Do you have char set to be signed or unsigned?

Comment: Please show the implementation of your macro/function KEY_F().  And, which line is gcc warning you about?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A char is a number between -128 and 127. KEY_F(9) probably is a value outside of that range.

Use:

- unsigned char, or
- int, or
- (char) KEY_F(9)

Or even better, use a debugger and determine sizeof(KEY_F(9)) to make sure it's a byte and not a short.

Comment: Casting KEY_F(9) to char might loose information depending on the implementation of that macro. Also, char is either signed or unsigned depending on the platform defaults and often compiler switches.

Comment: True true, and it's been a while since I played in C. I always used types for string characters anyway and always used unsigned char for the type, so I haven't run into this ever...

Comment: Note that casting to char will remove the compiler error, but it will likely not behave correctly!

Answer (score 9):

Well, KEY_F(9) would be 273 (see curses.h) which exceeds the range of char (-128,127).

Comment: The range of char depends on whether char is signed or unsigned. However, if curses.h is the source of the macro, then it is outside the range either way.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, `KEY_F(9)` is evaluating to something outside the range of `char`. The `switch` statement is assuming that because its argument is a `char`, that all case labels will be also. Changing the `switch` to read `switch((unsigned int)ch)` will cure it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like KEY_F(9) must evaluate to something that is outside the range of a char.

Answer (score 0):

What everyone else said regarding the range for char.

I remember this from my early days writing C... you're probably calling decode_input from a loop, right? If the user presses something like F9, you're going to get two bytes in the keyboard buffer - and the first byte will be 0x0.